# How to view BizTalk orchestration source

Tags: visual-studio-2013, biztalk, biztalk-2013

**The problem:**

I get an eventlog entry that calls out a failure in my orchestration. The stack trace shows the method name from orchestration generated code that I can't see.

**What I tried:**

The solution presented [here](https://blog.tallan.com/2006/11/07/view-biztalk-orchestration-in-c/) doesn't work with visual studio version 12.

Any suggestions?

Comment: From my experience.. it's pointless idea to reverse engineere orchestrations. You will face with tons of c# code with autogenerated switch/case statements etc. In most cases error message or event log entries night point you to something.

Comment: I don't want to reverse engineer. I want to read the generated code to find where the exception in the eventlog is thrown from. It's hard to guess in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the Orchestrations DLL with **ILSpy** and see the code, also open the .odx file with Notepad, after **#endif // __DESIGNER_DATA** you can see some code that maybe helps you.

Is not posible to activate the Tracking for the Orchestration to see where it fails? I think is better option to find errors.

Comment: Tracking can't be enabled in production due to the volume of processing. It also contains sensitive data I'm not allowed to see. I'll try ILSpy. Thanks :)